# Git: How to share the repositories without flooding with nonsignificant commits?

Tags: linux, git, workflow

I have a repository with my code.
I write in my own computer but the environment to run it is in a remote computer, so I am working like this:

```
-> Local: 
|    Write
|    Commit
|    Push --------> company git server |
|                                      |
|  Remote                              |
|    Pull   <---------------------------
|    Compile
<--- Run
```

However,if I missed a colon, or add a newline or fix a name or all that sort of minor changes, I've been adding numerous non-significant commits and that for version control is not convenient at all.

I've thought of writing a script to sync both machines with Rsync, but not sure if that's the best way to do it.

In the end of the day I would like to have just important commits and not all the trash I am adding.

How would you guys/girls do it?

Comment: Where is the *push* pushing to?

Comment: Pushing to the remote repository of the company. So between save and compile I am using 4 commands and an intermediate computer! (add-commit-pushToRemote-pullFromRemote)

Comment: Then you should set up your local repository to know the repository on the compiling machine as a remote and push there. You can later "*force push*" changes you made with `git commit --amend`. Just make sure to only push to the companies repository when your commit is *really* fine, so you won't ever change history there.

Comment: Hi, thanks @FelixPalmen . I tried that but as I compile in that directory, git recognises it as a non-bare repository so it doesn't allow to push to it.  I tried ignoring the warning and I am able to push, the log is written but the files are not added of modified. Maybe the three-clients way is the less problematic! (From the compiling machine I can't see the other one so I cannot pull either)

Comment: sorry, this was wrong, but the other way around works: you can **pull** from any other repository, bare or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not bother about it at all. While it is true that you can use `git rebase -i` ([docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)) or (in other circumstances, not for your particular case) `git merge --squash` ([docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)) to get rid of small, inconsequential, commits, I do not see a problem to solve.

`git` is *very* efficient at tracking small changes over many commits. You are not wasting much space. The worst that could happen is that someone else sees this. If a colleague challenges you about it, you can inform them that you prefer to commit early and often (which is a common trope with git, google for it and you find supporting sites like [this](https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitBestPractices/) or [that](http://www.databasically.com/2011/03/14/git-commit-early-commit-often/)). It's the same as the old "save early, save often" for general applications.

`git` is designed to work well with frequent, granular commits. Especially, merge operations don't care in the slightest how many commits are between the 3 involved commits.

Be especially careful with rebasing already pushed commits, that will lead to major headaches unless you have very tight control (and knowledge) about who already has your commits in their respective repository.

Comment: Thanks! What bothers me is also the ritual of add-commit-push-pull for any little change, I feel like I spend more time in doing that than in the actual editing!

Comment: Then you might want to take a look at what takes so long to do it, really. For me, it is a matter of a few seconds to press a few hotkeys in my editor (but, granted, I spend significant time to configure my environment for slick, streamlined work).

Comment: Indeed, I should do that. I was being too lazy to unleash the capabilities of emacs. Thanks!

Comment: Ah! I am using Emacs myself. Check out magit, it is great for very quickly adding, committing etc. right from the editor. @ARamirez

Answer (score 1):

1. git is much better (more effective) synchronisation tool that rsync because it stores much more meta-information. rsync has to recheck every file every time while git compares object hashes at both sides.
2. If you don't like you have too many small not very interesting commits — use `git rebase --interactive` and squash them into commits they fix or squash them together in one Big Fix commit.